# SAS do I need to drop an array after creating it?

Tags: sas

I was using the following code to create an array from the dataset:

```
DATA REPLACED;
    SET TPS_DROPPED;
    array arr_jin(*) _numeric_;
    do i=1 to dim(arr_jin);
        if arr_jin(i) = . then arr_jin(i) = 0;
    end;
    drop i arr_jin;
RUN;
```

However, i got the following error log:

```
ERROR 241-185: The array arr_jin is not allowed in a DROP/KEEP/RENAME context.
WARNING: The variable arr_jin in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.
```

Is it true that generally arrays don't need to be dropped after creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ARRAY in a SAS data step is not a variable so there is nothing to DROP.

If you did want to drop the actual variables that you are using the array to reference then you would need to list those variables names on the DROP statement.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit further: an array in SAS is just a convenience, it's not a data type of its own.  SAS only has [numeric column] and [character column] as data types, everything else is convenience.